# GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: fatal-error, uncaught-exception, guzzle

### This is the whole error

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)**